# Is there a way to get outerHTML of only the top element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Visitors to my page can set the background of the body to a color or an image.  These changes end up inline as something like:

```
<body style="background-image: none;
 background-color: rgb(255, 51, 221);">
```

Now I'd like to get the string above that follows style= and use the parameters there to build a proper style string:

```
<style>
     body {
         background-image: none;
         background-color:rgb(255, 51, 221);
    }
</style>
```

The first problem is getting the inline style from the body tag.  If I do an outerHTML I get the HTML for body and everything in it.  I just want the  tag, with all it attributes.

Thanks fore any suggestions.

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong with the first method?

Comment: Also, your second method is strange. You can't have css inside script tags. And you usually don't use js to build a stylesheet. Basically, what Musa said...

Comment: Sorry. I meant to use style tags.  I edited the question to show this. Also, it's not one method or the other.  The user generates the first in line style through controls on the page.  I want to then save what they've done by placing it in a style block that will be included when they reload their "work" the next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use : `var style = $("body").attr("style");`

this will return body tag's style attribute.

and then:

```
$("head").append('<style> body{' + style + '} </style>');
```

Comment: Okay, but do you see any good reason for actually doing that?

Comment: No , but this is what he wants!

Comment: This answer is perfect!  Thanks.  To clear up what's going on, the user is able to change the background style through page controls. I then want to save what he's done by incorporating it into the page style sheet when the page is saved.  I just need the opening body tag, but an outerHTML to get it gets the entire body, so this is much better for me .

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
document.body.outerHTML.replace(document.body.innerHTML, "")
```

Comment: I think just getting the part I need will be quicker than getting the entire body and nulling out everything after the opening body tag.  But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply get the style of the body:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style;
```

The '[0]' assumes you only have one body.  I only have one body.  ;)